# Dockerfile: is it necessary to specify which user before perform a RUN?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I' looking to a Dockerfile created by someone on Github
and I noticed that every time in the Docker file is defined a RUN, it is preceded by a USER username directive.

Is it mandatory? Or it is set Cascading style?

```
USER root
RUN commandA
USER www
RUN commandB 
.... 
RUN commandC
```

which user would be to perform commandC? the latest declared (www)?
Or there's something else (some other Docker command that could change it to default , apart USER obviously) Maybe the RUN itself after performing will reset the user?

Or is it just to be more verbose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary, no. It's always good practise to provide a `USER` for the Dockerfile to avoid running everything as `root`, however sometimes builds will need to flip back and forward. That's where you'll likely see:

```
...
USER alice
RUN ... // do stuff
USER root
RUN ... // do super privileged stuff
USER alice
CMD ... // run my app as non-privileged user
...
```

If you don't need to flip back and forward, then a single `USER` directive will cascade down to all the instructions below it.

```
...
USER alice
RUN ... // as alice
WORKDIR ...
RUN ... // as alice
ENV ... 
RUN ... // as alice
CMD ... // as alice
...
```

Answer (score 2):

> which user would be to perform commandC?

If there's no `USER` command between `commandB` and `commandC`, it's the user `www` to run `commandC`, from the [official docs of USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user):

> The USER instruction sets the user name or UID to use when running the image and for any RUN, CMD and ENTRYPOINT instructions that **follow** it in the Dockerfile

So you only need to use `USER user` to switch the user at the place you really need to, not every `RUN` command. By the way, `USER` also applies to `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`, which means the user in the last `USER` command is also the user to run your process in container.